# Reflect all tables not owned by user but having granted synonyms

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

We have some tables not owned by our user, but the user has granted access through synonyms.

We are able to reflect single tables using `sqlalchemy.Table` and [`oracle_resolve_synonyms`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html#synonym-dblink-reflection), but using this dialect parameter with `MetaData.reflect()` doesn't return the tables, even if the docs say that the param will be passed to the downstream Table reflections.

Is it because `MetaData.reflect()` can't enumerate the tables not owned by the user?

Is there any other option to reflect synonyms without having to reflect table by table?

**EDIT**

The following works:

```
mytable = sqlalchemy.Table('mytable',
                           meta,
                           autoload=True,
                           autoload_with=engine,
                           oracle_resolve_synonyms=True)
```

but not the following:

```
meta.reflect(bind=engine, oracle_resolve_synonyms=True)
```

Comment: Plesae show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @buhtz I've edited my question with the solutions tried so far

Answer (score 0):

The source code of MetaData.reflect() explains the behaviour.
The metadata instantiates a sqlalchemy.Table() for each table returned by engine.all_tables(). If no 'schema' parameter is included, this translates to a [dialet.get_table_names()](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_1_2_13/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/base.py#L1255) call which **returns the tables owned by the user**.
This means that MetaData.reflect() won't benefit from the usage of oracle_resolve_synonyms, which will only be passed down to sqlalchemy.Table().